# How to call a certain cell from xtabs output

Tags: r

I have this output of xtabs :

```
IsuP<-xtabs(~IsuP+glm_pred_response,data=test)
    glm_predict_response
IsuP  0  1
   0 67 35
   1 54 44
```

I would like to sum up the value of the left upper cell and the value of the right lower cell (67+44) How can I call those cells values only ?
**An update**: How can I get each cell by itself like taking the "35" and add it to "54" or any other combination?

Comment: Hello, etienne, I just update my question as I would like to know how to access each member of the xtabs output.

Comment: Seriously, have you even tried anything? Like doing `IsuP[, 1]` or `IsuP[1, ]` or anything at all?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I thought that xtabs has its own function to get specific cell's value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Isup[1,1]` for first row first column and so on

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sum(IsuP[!col(IsuP)-row(IsuP)])
```